Azure App Service Flask Deployment Error: "Failed to Respond to HTTP Pings on Port 8000; Site Start Failed. Check Container Logs for Debugging."
We have started working with Flask and with immersive service reader.
Everything is working fine when we run the immersive service in debug mode from Visual Studio code. BUT, when we start deploying the the Flask Web app with Immersive Reader in one of our WebApp in Azure. It is giving us an error. Please note: We are deploying it by a ZIP file mentioned over the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Czip-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli
We have gone through each and every steps mentioned in the link but still we are getting below result. (look at the attached image).

Then, After checking the logs in WebApp we find the error as given below : (when the service has been published and we try to call our deployed WebApp)

"Container api-aiml-learning-immersivereader-mpn-eastus_0_8947b5bf for site api-aiml-learning-immersivereader-mpn-eastus has exited, failing site start
Container api-aiml-learning-immersivereader-mpn-eastus_0_8947b5bf didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging. "
We is the page that we are expecting when we run the WebApp.

For further details, here is the code that we have used from samples provided as sample.
app.py code
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import requests
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

AZURE_CLIENT_ID = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID']
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET']
AZURE_TENANT_ID = os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
AZURE_RESOURCE = 'https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default'

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/get_token', methods=['GET'])

def get_token():

    url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{AZURE_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    data = {
        'client_id': AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'scope': AZURE_RESOURCE,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        token = response.json().get('access_token')
        return jsonify({'access_token': token})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Unable to fetch token'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

helpers.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('immersiveReaderButton').addEventListener('click', launchImmersiveReader);
});

function launchImmersiveReader() {
    fetch('/get_token')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log("data" ,data);
            if (data.access_token) {
                const token = data.access_token;
                console.log(token);
                const subdomain = '';  // Replace with your subdomain if necessary

                const content = {
                    title: "Immersive Reader Demo",
                    chunks: [
                        {
                            content: document.getElementById('contentToRead').innerHTML,
                            mimeType: 'text/html'
                        }
                    ]
                };

                const options = {
                    readAloudOptions: {
                        voice: 'en-US-JennyNeural',
                        speed: 1.0
                    },
                    uiLang: 'en'
                };

                ImmersiveReader.launchAsync(token, subdomain, content, options)
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log('Immersive Reader launched successfully');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error launching Immersive Reader:', error);
                    });
            } else {
                console.error('Error fetching token:', data.error);
            }
        })
        
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching token:', error);
        });
        console.log(ImmersiveReader.launchAsync);
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Immersive Reader</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ircdname.azureedge.net/immersivereadersdk/immersive-reader-sdk.1.4.0.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Immersive Reader Demo</h1>
    <!-- The button with id 'immersiveReaderButton' -->
    <button id="immersiveReaderButton">Launch Immersive Reader</button>
    <!-- The paragraph with id 'contentToRead' -->
    <p id="contentToRead">This is some text to be read by the Immersive Reader.</p>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{{ url_for('static', filename='helpers.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>


Are you trying the same sample code as given in the Doc. @riddhi

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am providing the 'index.html' , 'helpers.js', 'app.py', 'requirements.txt' , and environment file in my code. The application works correctly on localhost; however, I am encountering issues after deploying the code to Azure App Services.

@riddhi please share the Python (Django or Flask) code you tried  with azure-cognitive-services in text format.

Please post error message as text, and not images.  As people with screen readers would have issues, and it also effects searches.

@Dijkgraaf , I have included the error in text in Question.

@riddhi Instead of using app.run(debug=True) use app.run(host=
'0.0.0.0', port=8000).

@riddhi If possible, share your helper.js and index.html files.

@DasariKamali, I have included the code for 'helpers.js' and 'index.html' in the question.

@DasariKamali, Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have already tried it, and it did not work. Do you have any other recommendations?

@riddhi Add gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 main:app in the Startup command in the Azure appservice and try again.

@DasariKamali, We manually added the startup command in Azure App Services and also tried using the startup.txt file, but neither approach worked.

@riddhi Try to create a new azure app service and deploy it again.

@DasariKamali, We have also attempted to resolve the issue by creating another Azure App Service and another Cognitive Service in the same manner, but the error persists. Therefore, it seems likely that there are shortcomings in our deployment steps. Could you please suggest a comprehensive, end-to-end approach for deployment?

@DasariKamali, Thank you for your answer! It helped a lot. I also found one of the issues in my file and have added it in my answer.

@riddhi I'm glad to know the issue was resolved.

I tried your code, deployed the project to the Azure app service without any issues.
I ran the below command for zip deployment.
az webapp deploy --resource-group <resourcegroupname> --name <azurewebappname> --src-path <zipfilepath>


Azure App Service Output:

Second Approach :-
Below are the steps to deply the project from VS code with Azure Extension.
Go to Azure Extension select your subsciption under App Services > Web app > Deploy to Web App as shown below,

Choose your project path and deploy as below,

Azure App service output :


While reviewing the error log file, I discovered the following issue:

I resolved this error by adding Werkzeug==3.0.3 to my requirements.txt file.
